# How to watch for variable changes at all levels in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, dom-events, watch

I have this variable in NodeJS:

```
var toWatch = {
    count: 3,
    name: {
        first: "Foo",
        last: "Bar"
    }
}
```

And I want to fire a function when any value of it changes. For example, `toWatch.name.first = "ABC"` and `toWatch.newProperty = 123` would both trigger this function.

How can I implement this function?

Comment: `->` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy would be the only way.

Comment: It would generally always be better to hook into whatever is changing the value to begin with.

Comment: https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object.watch() for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/object-watch-for-all-browsers)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn maybe not, I'm looking for a Node solution.

Comment: @Pointy, good lib, although looking at the source, it seems to be polling the variables. I am looking for a solution that will work with extremely large objects.

Comment: The linked code works in node. https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583#gistcomment-1429714

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Proxy` to observe set and get at a JavaScript object.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is that a variable property?

Comment: @adelriosantiago See first [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331711/how-to-watch-for-variable-changes-at-all-levels-in-nodejs/46331750#comment79624240_46331711) posted at Question, also [Is JavaScript Proxy supposed to intercept direct changes to underlying object like Object.Observe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40011480/), [How to detect when a JavaScript object variable is accessed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41405080/)