# Event listener on data change in array node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array with size of 3. I need to call a function dynamically when the array value is changed. Any idea?

```
var arr = ["","",""];

arr[0] = 'first value is chagned';
arr[1] = 'second value is chagned';


function arrFunction(){
    console.log('Array value changed')
}
```

**Expected output**

Array value changed

Array value changed

.

I know we can achive this by calling function directly like below. For your reference, I gave these inputs. I can not directly call function like below

```
var arr = ["","",""];

arr[0] = 'first value is chagned';
arrFunction()
arr[1] = 'second value is chagned';
arrFunction()

function arrFunction(){
    console.log('Array value changed')
}
```

Comment: why not use a function to change the value and call print together?

Comment: For your reference, I gave these inputs. I can not directly call this function

Comment: I think you might be after using a proxy -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610242/detecting-changes-in-a-javascript-array-using-the-proxy-object

Comment: I will check and let you know here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your target support [`Proxies`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) this is easy to do:

```js
let observe = (obj, fn) => new Proxy(obj, {
    set(obj, key, val) {
        obj[key] = val;
        fn(obj)
    }
});

arr = observe(['', '', ''], arr => {
    console.log('arr changed! ', arr)
});

arr[0] = 'first value is chagned';
arr[1] = 'second value is chagned';
```