# Javascript observer or proxy without all changes going through proxy

Tags: javascript, arrays, observers, proxy-pattern

I'm writing a subclass of arrays in Javascript to have better support for matrix operations (I know others exist, this is partially for me to re-teach myself linear algebra), and what I want is to have some properties that are reset whenever any values in the matrix are adjusted. Some calculations like the determinant are computationally intensive, and I'd like to be able to store them to avoid re-calculation, but then they need to be reset to null whenever any matrix elements are changed.

Essentially, it seems like what i want is the deprecated [Array.observe()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/observe). And the replacement, proxies, seem like a lot of overhead for this one thing. As alluded to in some of the comments on [Detecting Changes in a Javascript Array using the proxy object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610242/detecting-changes-in-a-javascript-array-using-the-proxy-object) that were not directly addressed, I don't want to have to access my matrices only ever through proxies. I use a lot of handy `[i][j]` indexing and `[mat[i], mat[j]] = [mat[j], mat[i]]` in the code I've written so far.

```
class Matrix extends Array {
  constructor() {
    var args  = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(arguments[i])) {
        args.push(new Matrix(...arguments[i]));
      } else {
        args.push(arguments[i]);
      }
    }
    super(...args);
    this._determinant = null;
  }
  determ(forceRecalculate = false) {
    if (this._determinant === null || forceRecalculate) {
        this.upperEchelon();
    }
    return this._determinant;
  }
  upperEchelon(reduced = false) {
  //There's a lot of code here but in the process of doing this other thing
  //you get 99% of the way to calculating the determinant so it does this
  this._determinant = factor;
  }
}
```

Basically, I want anything like `mat[0][0] = 10` or `mat.push([2,4,5])` that updates the values in the matrix to set `mat._determinant = null`. Or any equivalent method of flagging that it needs to be re-calculated next time it's asked for. I'm not opposed to using proxies necessarily if someone can help me figure out the implementation, I would just rather have this set-to-null-on-update property be inherent to my class functionality.

What I really want is a way to overload base methods like `[]` a la C# so the functions that do the updating would trigger this without changing syntax, but I've resigned myself to not having that in JS.

Comment: Do any other methods of your Matrix need to *use* `_determinant`, or is it only going to be used (returned) when `determ` is called?

Comment: Don't use a `Proxy` to intercept property accesses... the resulting `Matrix` instances would be extremely slow.

Comment: @CertainPerformance There are a number of methods that need either `_determinant` or the return value of `determ()` (I don't really care which one and I know I could probably replace `determ()` with a proper getter). It's pretty commonly needed by a lot of the methods, and I'd like to not have to recalculate it more than necessary if possible.

Comment: Thanks, is it also *set* by multiple methods, or only by `upperEchelon`? (eg. whenever you need a new determinant, could you call `upperEchelon` (or some other method) to set the new value as desired, with the expensive operation?)

Comment: `upperEchelon` is the fastest way to calculate it so it should be the only method that needs to set it. The reason `determ()` has the little `=== null` logic was in the hope that I could set it equal to null on update and save the recalculation until the value was actually needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a Proxy would work, it would also be pretty slow. A different approach would be for every method that needs to use the value of `_determinant` go through a *different* function first to check to see if the `_determinant` needs to be updated (and if so, updates it). This way, the expensive recalculation is not done every time the array changes, but only just in time for the result to be used. For example:

```js
class Matrix extends Array {
  constructor() {
    var args  = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      if (Array.isArray(arguments[i])) {
        args.push(new Matrix(...arguments[i]));
      } else {
        args.push(arguments[i]);
      }
    }
    super(...args);
    this._determinant = null;
  }
  // next method is effectively a recursive deep join
  // could also use toString if it doesn't interfere with anything else
  getString() {
    const itemsStr = this.map((item) => (
    item instanceof Matrix
      ? item.getString()
      : item
    ))
    .join(',');
    const result = '[' + itemsStr + ']';
    return result;
  }
  getDeterm() {
    const newString = this.getString();
    if (newString !== this._lastString) {
      this._lastString = newString;
      this.upperEchelon();
    }
    return this._determinant;
  }
  upperEchelon() {
    console.log('running upperEchelon');
    this._determinant = Math.random();
  }
}

const m = new Matrix([2, 3, 4], 5);
console.log(m.getDeterm());
// Not calculated again:
console.log(m.getDeterm());
// Mutation, next call of getDeterm will run upperEchelon:
m[0][0] = 1;
console.log(m.getDeterm());
```

Comment: This is quite clever! And it works like a charm. Thanks so much!