# Is it possible to implement " addEventListener" type of capability for normal JavaScript Array objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, addeventlistener, eventemitter

I was working on a visualization library in JS and was wondering if something like this is possible?

```
const my_arr = [];

my_arr.addEventListener('push', (item) => {
    console.log(`${item} was pushed in my_arr`);
})


my_arr.push(3);        //should give "3 was pushed in my_arr"
```

Comment: The only way to do this would be to modify `Array.prototype`, which is a really bad idea.

Comment: Would something like `Proxy` work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610242/detecting-changes-in-a-javascript-array-using-the-proxy-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to watch for array changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes)

Comment: @N-Raj this depends very much on HOW MUCH do you want to be able to see. Do you need `arr[10]=item`? Do you need `arr.sort()`? Do you need `arr[10].data=data`? It may be easier to use a library if you need a lot

Answer (score 1):

you can overload the push method:

```js
const my_arr = [];

my_arr.real_push = my_arr.push;  // save my_arr.push  real method

my_arr.push = function( item )   // overload my_arr.push  method
  {
  my_arr.real_push( item );      // perform the push...
  console.log(`${item} was pushed in my_arr`);
  }


/// test :
my_arr.push(3);  //  3 was pushed in my_arr  
my_arr.push(55); // 55 was pushed in my_arr

console.log(  my_arr)
```

Answer (score -3):

See [documentation about custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent).

```
document.body.addEventListener('addItem', e => {
  this.my_arr.push(e.detail.item)
  cosole.log(`${item} was pushed in my_arr`)
})
```